# gtk3 keep crashing

Tags: gtk3

trying to gtk-3 based application

```
(audacious:10165): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:289:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(audacious:10165): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:323:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(audacious:10165): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1828:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(audacious:10165): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1845:21: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(audacious:10165): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1861:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(audacious:10165): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2146:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(audacious:10165): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:16:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(audacious:10165): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:93:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(audacious:10165): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:183:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(audacious:10165): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:503:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(audacious:10165): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:850:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(audacious:10165): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:925:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(audacious:10165): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:941:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(audacious:10165): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:957:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(audacious:10165): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:1012:21: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(audacious:10165): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:1020:21: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(audacious:10165): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:1034:21: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(audacious:10165): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:1103:21: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(audacious:10165): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:1237:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(audacious:10165): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gnome-panel.css:94:21: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(audacious:10165): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: nautilus.css:18:18: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(audacious:10165): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: nautilus.css:18:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(audacious:10165): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: nautilus.css:81:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(audacious:10165): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: nautilus.css:86:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(audacious:10165): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: nautilus.css:145:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(audacious:10165): Gtk-WARNING **: Style property "border-top-left-radius" is not gettable

(audacious:10165): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/buildd-glib2.0_2.35.8-1-amd64-lGLf9n/glib2.0-2.35.8/./gobject/gtype.c:4234: type id `0' is invalid

(audacious:10165): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: can't peek value table for type `' which is not currently referenced
Segmentation fault
```

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be your gtk-3 theme that is incompatible with your gtk-3 library. Try removing the theme from .config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini and relaunching the aplication.

Comment: i changed theme which compatible with 3.8 and engine ..thanks it works

Answer (score 1):

the actually important part is:

```
(audacious:10165): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/buildd-glib2.0_2.35.8-1-amd64-lGLf9n
/glib2.0-2.35.8/./gobject/gtype.c:4234: type id `0' is invalid

(audacious:10165): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: can't peek value table for type `' which is
not currently referenced Segmentation fault
```

which means that the code is trying to access an instance of an unknown type. this is most likely a bug in audacious, so you should ask the audacious developers; it will be easier if you gather a stack trace that shows the callers list for that particular warning. you can use gdb and the G_DEBUG environment variable to retrieve the stack trace - just follow the instructions available on the GNOME wiki: https://live.gnome.org/GettingTraces

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting any crashes, but this is the only question I could find with this error message that's been bugging the crap out of me:

`Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: nautilus.css:86:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.`

I'm programming in C and Python currently and I got several of these with every run. I've been looking for a solution for this for awhile and I finally dug into it today out of frustration with my clogged up terminal output. The solution is INCREDIBLY SIMPLE!!

I run xfce4 on Arch Linux with the "dusk theme". I was getting this error for a gtk.css file on line 72.
By grepping the output of "find", I found the file in "/usr/share/themes/Xfce-dusk/gtk-3.0/gtk.css". I confirmed by moving the line down 2 lines, and ran my program again. The error message then referenced line 74!

On Line 72 I changed it from, "text-shadow: 1 1 white;" to "text-shadow: 1px 1px white;".

Voila! No more annoying error messages!